# The number of sections in the table view is not equal to what I set

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, viewdidappear

The code is very simple, the customer class, **ChecklistViewController**, is inherited from **UITableViewController**. The Swift source code is connected to a tableViewController in the storyboard with the default prototype cell untouched.

```
class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10 // I set 10 sections here
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        print("\(tableView.numberOfSections)")// prints out "1" ???
    }

}
```

**Problem:**

I asked the data source function to create 10 sections for the table view, while, later, it told that the table view only has 1 section in the **viewDidAppear** function. Isn't it supposed to print out 10? why 1?

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: `let tableView = UITableView()`, that's a whole new object (while since you have `UITableViewController`, you have already a `UITableView`, and `numberOfSections(in tableView:)` hasn't been called yet before a `reloadData()`$

Comment: @Larme I changed the code inside the viewDidAppear to     **print(self.numberOfSections(in: self.tableView))** and the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are needlessly creating a new, empty table with no data source or delegate. You are then asking that needless table how many sections it has. Since it has no data source, it returns the default of 1 section.

Instead of creating an extra table view, reference the proper table view created by the table view controller.

Change `viewDidAppear` to:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    print("\(self.tableView.numberOfSections)")
}
```

Now this will access the real table view that is created by the table view controller. This should give the proper result of 10.

Note that `self.` isn't actually needed. I put it here just to make it clear which `tableView` is being referenced.